# CSS to apply only on IE8 in compatibility mode (no IE8 no IE7)?

Tags: css

is there a way to add a css which will work only for IE8 in compatibility mode, but will not if IE7 or IE8 or (obviously any other browser) ???

My CSS is trivial

```
h1 {
   font-size:14px;
}
```

but that must font-size must only work on IE8 (compatibility mode)

NOTE:
I know how to write a conditional statement to spot IE8... but I don't know how to do it for IE8 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to apply to just IE8 Compatibility mode. However, IE8CM will display exactly the same IE7, because it is an IE7 emulator. You could use something like the following code, but it will also apply to IE7:

```
<!--IE9 compatibility mode & IE8:-->
  <!--[if IE 8]>
    <p>Welcome to Internet Explorer 8.</p>
  <![endif]-->

<!--IE8 compatibility mode & IE7:-->
  <!--[if IE 7]>
    <p>Welcome to Internet Explorer 7.</p>
  <![endif]-->
```

Is there any reason that it can't also apply to IE7? Any hack that you're doing that would fix a problem compatibility mode in IE8 should also be needed in IE7.

Answer (score 2):

CSS hack for IE8, like this:

```
h1{font-size:14px\0;}
```

Comment: I saw it here...It said this way maybe also effect on Opera,but not sure.You can try it.http://www.cnblogs.com/WuQiang/archive/2011/08/23/2150240.html

Comment: it also include that style in iE9 so this hack not work only for IE8

Answer (score 0):

You should add code below before html tag in your code:

```
<!--if IE 8>
<html class="IE8">
<[endif]-->
<html>
...
</html>
```

and in CSS file, do this:

```
.IE8 h1{
font-size:14px;
}
```

This will work only for IE8.

Comment: The question was about IE 8 ∗compatibility mode∗ (aka. Quirks Mode).

Answer (score 0):

use css hack :

```
     body{
         color:red;           /*every browser*/
         color:blue\9;        /*IE8 or below*/
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility mode unless there is a modified DocType renders as IE 7 or less, so if it is in compatibility mode, it will often render also in IE 7.

However, you can still do it: if you check the user agent string, you can differentiate it that way. IE 8 and newer include the word 'Trident' in the user agent string, so if it is rendering as IE 7 or less, but the word Trident does show up in the uagent, then it must be in compatibility mode.

While most people would not find this necessary, I did have reason for it. In one of my previous projects, it was needed to tell people to use the compatibility mode option until we were able to modify our applications to handle the newer browsers. Not everyone reads instructions, so a message that pops up is often the best way to tell people what to do.

This modified version of a script I wrote and put in the head of the document did the trick:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/i)) { 
   ie__mode=' not_ie_compatibility_mode';
(!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/i)&&document.documentMode<8)?ie__mode=' ie_compatibility_mode':''; } 
</script>
```

So then the javascript variable ie_mode would be set to either: "ie_compatibility_mode" or "not_ie_compatibility_mode"

If you were to add document.documentElement.className+=ie__mode; to the script so as to add a css class to the document itself like so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/i)) { 
   ie__mode=' not_ie_compatibility_mode';
(!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/i)&&document.documentMode<8)?ie__mode=' ie_compatibility_mode':'';
document.documentElement.className+=ie__mode; } 
</script>
```

Then you would be able to use css in the document for either mode. Example styles:

```
<style type="text/css">

    html { color:#000000; }

    /* default settings: start with all items 'off' */

    .hide_element { display:none; visibility:hidden; }

    .ie_compatibility_mode .display_compatibility_mode { visibility:visible; display:block; color:#FF9900; }

    .not_ie_compatibility_mode .display_not_compatibility_mode { visibility:visible; display:block; color:#666666; }

</style>
```

and in the body you could then do this:

```
<body>

If you are using internet explorer there will be more here: 

<br><br>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    if (document.documentMode) document.write("which ie mode: "+document.documentElement.className);
</script>

<br><br>

<div class="hide_element display_compatibility_mode">
   This is in compatibility mode. [this should show up in orange]
</div>

<div class="hide_element display_not_compatibility_mode">
   This is not in compatibility mode. [this should be show up in blue]
</div>

</body>
```

Here is the complete working page with all the parts put together:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Class Setting / Detect Compatibility Mode Example - Jeff Clayton</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/i)) { 
   ie__mode=' not_ie_compatibility_mode';
(!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/i)&&document.documentMode<8)?ie__mode=' ie_compatibility_mode':'';
document.documentElement.className+=ie__mode; } 
</script>

<style type="text/css">

/* default settings: start with all items 'off' */

.hide_element { display:none; visibility:hidden; }

.ie_compatibility_mode .display_compatibility_mode { visibility:visible; display:block; color:#FF9900; }

.not_ie_compatibility_mode .display_not_compatibility_mode { visibility:visible; display:block; color:#0000FF; }

</style>

</head>

<body>

If you are using internet explorer there will be more here: 

<br><br>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    if (document.documentMode) document.write("which ie mode: "+document.documentElement.className);
</script>

<br><br>

<div class="hide_element display_compatibility_mode">
   This is in compatibility mode. [this should show up in orange]
</div>

<div class="hide_element display_not_compatibility_mode">
   This is not in compatibility mode. [this should show up in blue]
</div>

</body>
</html>
```