# CSS to apply only on IE11 in compatibility mode of IE9 (not on IE9 native)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I know how to write a CSS conditional statement to spot IE9 but I don't know how to do it for **IE9 compatibility mode running in IE11**. This is kind of the same as the question posted 3 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083829/css-to-apply-only-on-ie8-in-compatibility-mode-no-ie8-no-ie7). I'm reasking for newer browsers after a long time. Is there a way today to do this for newer versions specified here?
Say, here is code sample (Values not accurate):

```
<!-- Use this in IE11 native -->
table#mystyle td.yes {
   width: 207px;
}

<!-- Use this in IE11 when compatibilty mode is in IE9 -->
table#mystyle td.yes {
   width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: is there a specific style that you are trying to target , that might be alot easier to do then try to write styles based on the clients browser - which is never a good idea

Answer (score -1):

try this code it might be helpful
`

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
  /* IE CSS RULES HERE */
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

`

For the IE supported css

[click here](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/moving-ie-specific-css-into-media-blocks/media-tests/)

Comment: This doesn't seem t o answer the question stated by the OP. He needs to style something when it is browsed from IE11 in IE9 comnpatibility mode. You just show a conditional style for IE in general.